# Travis CI Build Keeps Failing

Tags: javascript, deployment, build, travis-ci

I have a project that I am trying to incorporate Travis CI into for testing.

For the life of me, Travis CI keeps 'failing' when I do a Pull Request and/or push to my repos on GitHub.

Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
before_script:
  -npm install -g webpack
  -npm install -g mocha
  -npm install -g chai
  -npm start
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

Here is the message from Travis CI about the error:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-f87d2e7f.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-7
system_info
Build system information
Build language: node_js
Build group: stable
Build dist: precise
Build image provisioning date and time
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux Version
3.13.0-29-generic
Cookbooks Version
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
GCC version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
LLVM version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Pre-installed Ruby versions
ruby-1.9.3-p551
Pre-installed Node.js versions
v0.10.36
Pre-installed Go versions
1.4.1
Redis version
redis-server 2.8.19
riak version
2.0.2
MongoDB version
MongoDB 2.4.12
CouchDB version
couchdb 1.6.1
Neo4j version
1.9.4
RabbitMQ Version
3.4.3
ElasticSearch version
1.4.0
Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6
Installed Firefox version
firefox 31.0esr
PhantomJS version
1.9.8
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
fix.CVE-2015-7547
$ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_source_Sources.gz is not what the server reported 5886 5888
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntugis_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 36669 36677
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntugis_ppa_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 36729 36733
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 221 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,844 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,216 B disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 [2,943 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 [84.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 [1,179 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.13 [4,637 kB]
Fetched 8,844 kB in 0s (31.7 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 69991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6-dev 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10.13_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6-dev ...
Preparing to replace libc-dev-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-dev-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.13_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc-dev-bin ...
Preparing to replace libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.13_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc-bin ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.13) ...
(Reading database ... 69991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.13_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6 ...
Setting up libc6 (2.15-0ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.13) ...
Setting up libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.13) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
git.checkout
0.46s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/NAME/mood.ly.git NAME/mood.ly
Cloning into 'NAME/mood.ly'...
remote: Counting objects: 1183, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (507/507), done.
remote: Total 1183 (delta 616), reused 1170 (delta 608), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1183/1183), 665.78 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (616/616), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd NAME/mood.ly
$ git checkout -qf 6bb7813f901f8d3cca359f8a9a1124df4dda86fe
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
Updating nvm to v0.31.0
2.25s$ nvm install node
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.1.0/node-v6.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Now using node v6.1.0 (npm v3.8.6)
$ node --version
v6.1.0
$ npm --version
3.8.6
$ nvm --version
0.31.0
install
47.43s$ npm install 
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN excluding symbolic link index.js -> lib/sass.js
npm WARN excluding symbolic link lib/index.js -> sass.js
mood.ly@1.0.0 /home/travis/build/NAME/mood.ly
├─┬ babel-cli@6.8.0 
│ ├─┬ babel-polyfill@6.8.0 
│ │ └── babel-regenerator-runtime@6.5.0 
│ ├── babel-runtime@6.6.1 
│ ├─┬ bin-version-check@2.1.0 
│ │ ├─┬ bin-version@1.0.4 
***A BUNCH OF OTHER DEPENDENCIES* (it goes over 30K characters so I had to redact it)**
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
0.00s$ -npm install -g webpack -npm install -g mocha -npm install -g chai -npm run build-server - export DISPLAY=:99.0 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
/home/travis/build.sh: line 45: eval: -n: invalid option
eval: usage: eval [arg ...]
The command "-npm install -g webpack -npm install -g mocha -npm install -g chai -npm run build-server - export DISPLAY=:99.0 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start" failed and exited with 2 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Would really appreciate some help/advice with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
The command "-npm install -g webpack -npm install -g mocha -npm install -g chai -npm run build-server - export DISPLAY=:99.0 - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

This line should be the hint. Your `npm` has a dash before it (i.e: `-npm`). Add a space between the `-` and `npm` in your configuration.

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g webpack
  - npm install -g mocha
  - npm install -g chai
  - npm start
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - that fixed a few things for sure. At least I'm not getting the same error but the build still fails.

The error I get now says:

`[nodemon] starting babel-node ./server/server.js --presets es2015 react
Mood.ly is listening on 8080
Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

The main issue I was having before was I had a `MySQL` config file with my `password` that was in `.gitignore` but since the build kept failing, I removed it and allowed it to be pushed.